# SQLのLIKE文で一致した部分から前後数文字を抽出したい

Tags: sql

下記のテーブルから

```
SELECT contents FROM sample WHERE contents LIKE '%mn%'
```

とすると、「jklmnopqr」が返ってきますが、「klmnop」のように、一致した部分の前後2文字を抽出する方法はありますか？

```
sample
+---+-----------+
|ID |  contents |
+---+---------- +
| 1 | abcdefghi |
| 2 | jklmnopqr |
| 3 | stuvwxyz  |
+---+-----------+
```

Comment: MySQLであれば、`SELECT @idx:=locate('mn', contents) _, substring(contents, if(@idx<=2,1,@idx-2), 6) \`match\` FROM sample WHERE contents LIKE '%mn%';` というなところでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQLなら substring に正規表現が記述できます

```
SELECT substring('jklmnopqr' from '.{0,2}mn.{0,2}');
```

MySQLでも 8.0+ なら regexp_replace で似たようなことができます

```
SELECT regexp_replace('jklmnopqr', '^.*?(.{0,2}mn.{0,2}).*?$', '$1', 1, 0, 'c');
```

MySQL < 8.0 なら、マッチ位置から前後数文字を切り出すロジックを地道に記述する他ないと思います

```
SELECT
  id,
  contents,
  substring(contents, left_index, right_index - left_index + 1)
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    contents,
    CASE
      WHEN ind = 0 THEN 0
      WHEN ind >= 3 THEN ind - 2
      ELSE 1
    END AS left_index,
    CASE
      WHEN ind = 0 THEN -1
      WHEN ind + length('mn') + 1 >= len THEN len
      ELSE ind + length('mn') + 1
    END AS right_index
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      contents,
      locate('mn', contents) AS ind,
      length(contents) AS len
    FROM (
      SELECT 1 AS id, 'jklmnopqr' AS contents
    ) sample
  ) sample
) sample;
```